# Printing to console works but printing to file is not working using logback

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, logback

- Imported the required jar files in to the build path in eclipse.
- Imported the slf4j Logger and LoggerFactory package name properly
- Created a logger instance from the
  `LoggerFactory.getLogger("classname");`

Below is the `logback.xml` file:

Tried with log4, logback access and not logback classic however, I am unable to print it to a file. I am trying to fix this over a week now with no luck

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- Tests run on modern PCs show that buffering related property -->
    <!-- "ImmediateFlush" has negligible impact and will be ignored.  -->
    <Append>true</Append>
    <File>log.txt</File>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c %p %t %m%n%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>debug</level>
    </filter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="theConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <logger name="com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </logger>
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="theConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute filename, in a directory that you have definitely write access? Also `File` and `Append` aren't capitalized.

Comment: Yes I tried absolute path as well. Do I have to escape the slashes in absolute path (in logback.xml)? File and Append should be capitalized?

Comment: Should _not_ be capitalized, but _are_ in your code sample.